# i keep having error on php with values that i sent with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm really stuck in ajax,

i don't have problem with simply sending values using form tag to PHP file.
but i want to make my program a bit more fancy using jquery and ajax. 
and i'm totally stuck for few days.

what i'm trying to do is when i click on some text (study progress in my code), it turns into an editing box
and when i finish editing,  it sends to variable "name" and update in PHP.
so i have to somehow send the value in the editing box in ajax,
but i keep having

> " Undefined index: name "

i searched on google a lot, but i couldn't find the answer for me.
can i get some help from here?

i want to put the values of what i edited to the variable `name` ;
and want to check on server side.

how can i put the values of what i edited to variable `name` and send 
to php in POST and check on server?

here is code that i made so far.

======HTML======

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullname">study progress</div>


<script>
  $('#fullname').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('');
    $('<input></input>')
      .attr({
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'fname',
        'id': 'txt_fullname',
        'size': '50',
        'value': name
    })
    .appendTo('#fullname');
$("#txt_fullname").focus().val("").val(name); 
});


$(document).on('blur','#txt_fullname', function(){
var name = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'practice_check.php',
  data : { "name" : name },
success: function(){
    $('#fullname').text(name);
     alert(name);
     location.replace("practice_check.php");
  }
});
});


</script>
```

======PHP  ( practice_check.php ) ======

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: I use this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 1):

You were wrong. You need to specify the url and if you want to get data in PHP you need to add data. I made a simple code. You can check full detail at this link : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting

```
var name = 'abc';

$.ajax({
    url: 'practice_check.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: name},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: opps sorry, i didn't write my post properly, i just edited, i did indeed, but i still have the problem

Comment: Did you check on check  devTools on browser . Switch to network tabs if you are using Chrome. Find your request and check the formdata

Answer (score 0):

first your ajax should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'practice_check.php',
    data : { "name" : name },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        //response will be the output of practice_check.php
        $('#fullname').text(name);
        alert(response.data);
    }
});
```

in you practice_check.php

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
// do your functions here .. then echo response like for example
if(strlen($name) < 3){ echo "oops invalid name"; }
else { echo "successfully checked with no errors"; }
```

Comment: Thank you ! but i've tried to put dataType before too, but i don't know why codes after dataType don't work when i put dayaType